# Javascript: more functions on one click button.Click counter

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make more functions on one click button. I am trying to detect how much the user is clicking. If the user clicks onetime: do something, If the user clicks second time: do something. if the user clicks for the third time: do something. But my code is not working at all. can someone tell me what is going on?

```
var ButtonClickEen = document.getElementById("buttonEen");
var ButtonClickTwee = document.getElementById('buttonTwee');
var clicks = 0;

buttonC.onclick = function(event){
    clicks += 1;
};

if (clicks === 1) {
    /* 1st click, Do something */
} if (clicks === 2) {
    /* 2nd click, Do something else */
};
```

Comment: FYI, you should cache your DOM references, I.E: `var twee = document.getElementById('twee')` to save you calling the method every time.

Comment: *"If the user clicks onetime: do something, If the user clicks second time: do something. if the user clicks for the third time: do something."* - Is that it, or does it go on..? can you share the HTML as well and you explain what exactly you want to do ..?

Comment: Hi @TJ thanks for your comment. Already solved the problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many script errors, starting with selection of elements from DOM at beginning, but main error is your click event function, which has to look like this:

```
var buttonC = document.getElementById("buttonC");
var clicks = 0;

buttonC.onclick = function(event){
    clicks += 1;

    if (clicks == 1) {
        alert('Click 1');
    } else if (clicks == 2) {
        alert('Click 2');
    } else {
        alert('Click 3 or more');
    };
};
```

Comment: Hi @skobaljic, Thanks for reaction! I will try it and let you know!

Comment: Please not what George has said in above comment, make sure the `ID` values are correct.